# Package conflict error while installing RPM

Tags: java, linux, rpm, nebula

I am getting following error while installing rpm created by netflix nebula:

```
yum localinstall demo-daemon-0:0.0.1-1.noarch
```

Transaction check error:

```
file /etc/rc.d from install of demo-daemon-0:0.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package chkconfig-1.7.2-1.el7.x86_64
file /etc/rc.d/init.d from install of demo-daemon-0:0.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package chkconfig-1.7.2-1.el7.x86_64
file /etc/rc.d from install of demo-daemon-0:0.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package initscripts-9.49.37-1.el7.x86_64
file /etc/rc.d/init.d from install of demo-daemon-0:0.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package initscripts-9.49.37-1.el7.x86_64
```

OS details:

```
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
          Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: you can edit existing rpm using rpmrebuild utility. using rpmrebuild -pe <file>. then delete the %dir conflicting entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't own `/etc/rc.d/`, `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`, etc. Take them out of the `%files` listing in the specfile and only list the files you actually provided.